# How to render a 404 in express

Tags: express

I want to render a 404 when a user accesses a particular page in express

I have the following code

```
app.use('/test.html', function( err, req, res, next ) {
   res.status(404).sendFile(path.join( __dirname, 'example','dist','error-4xx.html'));
});

app.use('/', express.static(path.join( __dirname, '..', 'example', 'dist')));
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this for a specific route you would do something like this:

```
app.get('/somepage', function(req, res){
    res.status(404).sendFile(path.join( __dirname, 'example','dist','error-4xx.html'));
}
```

*Note: app.use accepts 3 parameters, the request, the response and next (no error)*